# Should tuples be passed to macro?

Tags: elixir

The way tuples are handled seems to be not consistent:

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro a(x) do
    IO.inspect x
    quote do end
  end
end
```

`A.a {:a, :b}` prints `{:a, :b}` as expected, but `A.a {:a}` prints `{:{}, [line: 2], [:a]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros receive their arguments as quoted expressions, and in Elixir, tuples of length 2 are represented as themselves, and the rest are represented as `{:{}, _, [value1, value2, ...]}`:

```
iex(1)> Macro.escape {}
{:{}, [], []}
iex(2)> Macro.escape {1}
{:{}, [], [1]}
iex(3)> Macro.escape {1, 2}
{1, 2}
iex(4)> Macro.escape {1, 2, 3}
{:{}, [], [1, 2, 3]}
iex(5)> Macro.escape {1, 2, 3, 4}
{:{}, [], [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

If you inject these values into a `quote` using `unquote`, they'll be converted to the actual tuples automatically. We can see that using `Macro.to_string/2`:

```
iex(6)> Macro.to_string {:{}, [], [1, 2, 3]}
"{1, 2, 3}"
```

You can find more information about this in the [Quote and unquote -> Escaping](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html#escaping) Getting Started Guide.